# sqlite with iOS 5 issue

Tags: ios, ios5, sqlite

OK this is the case, I have the following query

```
INSERT INTO 'FoodListTBL' ('AutoNo','CHOCals','PrtCals', 'FatCals','CHOgram','PrtGram','FatGram','CatId', 'TimeTypeId','TotalCals','Visibl', 'IsActive','NameAr','NameEn','CountryId', 'TotalPerUnit','UnitId','PreferedBread1', 'PreferedMilk1','PreferedVeg1','PreferedFat1', 'PreferedFruit1','CauseAllergy','AllergyCatId', 'TotalLikes','NameDescEn','NameDescAr','ChoPerUnit','PrtPerUnit','FatPerUnit','Quantity','PreferedBread2','PreferedMilk2', 'PreferedVeg2','PreferedFat2', 'PreferedFruit2','IV','UV','InsertDate','InsertUser') VALUES (818,0,0, 45, 0, 0, 5, 17, 1, 45,1, 1, 'زبدة قليلة الدسم', 'Butter reduced fat', 0, 45, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'Butter reduced fat', 'زبدة قليلة الدسم', 0, 0, 45, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 492, 0, '-', '-' ),(819,0,0, 45, 0, 0, 5, 17, 1, 45,1, 1, 'زبدة', 'Butter regular', 0, 45, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'Butter regular', 'زبدة', 0, 0, 45, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 493, 1475, '-', '-')
```

this query executed successfully on iOS 6.X and failed on any iOS less than 5.X taking into consideration that any other insert query on other tables finished successfully on any iOS

and I've tried two codes for insert this is one of them

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
{   
    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(compiledStatement))
        NSLog( @"Error while inserting data: '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else NSLog(@"New data inserted");

    sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);       
}else
{
    NSLog( @"Error while inserting '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement)
```

and the result in the two cases is

> Error while inserting 'near ",":syntax error'

aging this query is functional on every thing except iOS < 6.0

any clues are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite before version 3.7.11 does not support the multi-record `INSERT` syntax.

Use multiple `INSERT` commands, or insert the records with `INSERT ... SELECT ... UNION ALL ...`.

Comment: But the same code with the same query is working sucessfully on iOS 6.0 I didn't change the sqlite version with iOS 6.0

Comment: And how can i know the version of the sqlite that i'm use, thanks

Comment: Use `SELECT sqlite_version();`; or better, just use the form that works in all versions.

Comment: the sqlite version i'm use is 3.7.13